# Converting .XLSB file to .XLSX in console with run excelcnv.exe on Windows Server 2012

Tags: excel, windows, xlsx, windows-server-2012-r2, xlsb

I'm using following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excelcnv.exe" -oice C:\test\test.xlsb C:\test\test.xlsx
```

On my workstation with Windows 10 it's work fine, but when I run it on Windows 2012 Server R2 by Administrator it giving me nothing: no errors, no converted files. Version of Microsoft office the same: 2007 and installation path the same.

Do I have any restrictions on Windows Server? How I can convert XLSB to XLSX on Windows Server?

Comment: Are you running the conversion from a service on the Windows Server machine?

Comment: I just login as Administrator by remote connection to Server and run it in `cmd` manually.